# Trying to create a xunit test for DBNull

Tags: c#, xunit, dbnull

I am trying to create a xunit test for a method that checks for DBNull.Value.  I am currently using InlineData to create the test but it is giving an error when attempting to use 'DBNull.Value' as my test param.

```
        [Theory]
        [InlineData(null)]
        [InlineData(DBNull.Value)]
        public void GetStringorNullNegativeTest(object value)
        {
            //arrange, act
            var _resultString = value == null ? "" : value.ToString().Trim();
            var _returnString = value.GetStringorNull();

            //assert
            Assert.NotEqual(_resultString, _returnString);
        }

    public static string GetStringorNull(this System.Object o)
    {
        if (o == null || o == DBNull.Value)
            return null;

        if (o is string)
        {
            string s = (string)o;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                return null;
            else
                return s.Trim();
        }

        return o.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

Is there a simple way to check for 'DBNull.Value' in the test without completely refactoring the test?

Comment: Use a different way of passing data to the test, such as `[MemberData]`. See this blog post for more information: https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/

Comment: When doing "expected vs actual" tests, your expected values should be const literals too, instead of calculated by the test, otherwise you'll end up with having to test-your-tests which is never fun.

Answer (score 2):

- C# only allows `const` expressions to be used as values for attributes, namely:

  - `String` literals (including `nameof()` expressions).
  - The `null` constant reference.
  - Integer and Float (`Single` and `Double`) literals.

    - ...but not Decimal `0M` literals.
  - `enum` members.
  - Other `const`.
  - `typeof()` expressions.
  - (and a few others I'm probably forgetting)
- Basically, with the exception of `String` values, reference-types cannot be used in attribute use-sites.
- `DBNull` is a `class`, i.e. a reference-type.
- `DBNull.Value` is a `public static readonly` field, not a `const` field.
- Therefore `DBNull.Value` cannot be used in an attribute use-site directly.

Instead, use some other means of representing a `DBNull`... for example:

```
public enum GetStringOrNullTestMode
{
    UseValue,
    UseDBNull
}

[Theory]
[InlineData(GetStringOrNullTestMode.UseValue, null)]
[InlineData(GetStringOrNullTestMode.UseValue, "")]
[InlineData(GetStringOrNullTestMode.UseValue, "abc123")]
[InlineData(GetStringOrNullTestMode.UseDBNull, null)]
public void GetStringorNullNegativeTest( GetStringOrNullTestMode mode, Object? value )
{
    if( mode == GetStringOrNullTestMode.UseDBNull ) value = DBNull.Value;

    // arrange, act
    var actual = value == null ? "" : value.ToString().Trim();
    var returnString = value.GetStringorNull();

    // assert
    Assert.NotEqual_resultString, _returnString);
}
```

Another approach is to use hand-written `[Fact]` methods that create and pass non-`const` values into the same orignal `[Theory]` test method, e.g.:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(null)]
[InlineData("")]
[InlineData("abc123")]
public void GetStringorNullNegativeTest( Object? value )
{
    if( mode == GetStringOrNullTestMode.UseDBNull ) value = DBNull.Value;

    // arrange, act
    var actual = value == null ? "" : value.ToString().Trim();
    var returnString = value.GetStringorNull();

    // assert
    Assert.NotEqual_resultString, _returnString);
}

[Fact]
public void GetStringorNullNegativeTestWithDBNull()
{
    this.GetStringorNullNegativeTest( value: DBNull.Value );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the MemberData option as suggested.  Changed to the below and it works.

```
        public static IEnumerable<object[]> DBNullObject =>
            new List<object[]>
            {
                new object[] { DBNull.Value }
            };

        [Theory]
        [MemberData(nameof(DBNullObject))]
        public void GetStringorNullNegativeTest(object value)
        {
            //arrange, act
            var _resultString = value == null ? "" : value.ToString().Trim();
            var _returnString = value.GetStringorNull();

            //assert
            Assert.NotEqual(_resultString, _returnString);
        }
```

Comment: Note that when you use `MemberData` you lose compile-time verification that the member's type matches the parameter-list of the test method.

Answer (score 0):

The following does require changing the way you're handling the test itself from `InlineData` to `MemberData`. Make your `GetStringorNullNegativeTest` test look like below, adding an additional `MemberData` method to facilitate any future tests too.

Similar to what Ken B was mentioning. Dai added an asterisks to understand the difference between the two types of test

What you have is the MemberData can run multiple tests, and more features than the `InlineData` restrictions of attributes.  I added your `null` test as well.

```
        [Theory]
        [MemberData(nameof(GetStringorNullNegativeTest_MemberData))]
        public void GetStringorNullNegativeTest(object value)
        {
            //arrange, act
            var _resultString = value == null ? "" : value.ToString().Trim();
            var _returnString = value.GetStringorNull();

            //assert
            Assert.NotEqual(_resultString, _returnString);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetStringorNullNegativeTest_MemberData()
        {
            yield return new object[] { null };
            yield return new object[] { DBNull.Value };
        }
```